# ABAP RAP Action button Error "Invalid Function Import Parameter"?

Tags: abap, sap-fiori, s4hana, rap

I have created a Fiori elements app using CDS annotations.
My app contains multi-select list report.

I created a Action button using lineItem annotation like below

```
{ type: #FOR_ACTION, position: 10, dataAction: 'que_post', label: 'tre', invocationGrouping: #CHANGE_SET }
```

And created action in Behavior Definition as well.

But when I select either one or multiple rows, I am having error "Parameter missing"
[image]

Following the error screenshot from my network:
[image]

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?
I want to select multiple rows and pass it into my ABAP RAP Action.

**Update**

My snippet from metadata for function import:

```xml
<FunctionImport Name="que_post" ReturnType="cds_z_p_quality_status_serv_def.DummyFunctionImportResult" m:HttpMethod="POST" sap:action-for="cds_z_p_quality_status_serv_def.DelQualityDetailsType">
  <Parameter Name="matnr" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="40"/>
  <Parameter Name="lifnr" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="10"/>
  <Parameter Name="charg" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="10"/>
  <Parameter Name="sernr" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="18"/>
  <Parameter Name="prueflos" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="12"/>
</FunctionImport>
```

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: You can always have a look in the SEGW how your particular Function Import ist defined. In your case it could just be a case-sensitive issue.

Comment: @JanW the case in metadata is small letters only. So, the case is fine. It's something else.

Comment: My troubleshooting approach to this problem would be: 1. check if I can get the function import of the odata service to work when I test it in the gateway client, 2. try again from the ui5 application like you are doing here, 3. check the request in the browsers network tab to see if it looks any different from the request I assembled in the gateway client. Can you do that for us?

Comment: Hi Philipp, If I call my action through jQuery GET method. It works. But it saying parameters missing when calling through oData.callFunction method or using but lineItem action Button.

Comment: @Philipp, this function import is working from GW_CLIENT as well

Comment: @Piyushaggarwal Most likely reason is that the parameters in your import are named slightly different from the attributes of your OData entity. Please check the request in the network tab of your browsers network tab to see if the request generated by UI5 looks any different from the requests you make yourself.

Comment: @Philipp, I am not passing the paramrers manually. I have marked matnr as my key paramter in CDS view and it is only required to RAP action. But it not getting passed in POST call.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using `action ( features : instance ) <ActionName>;` in BDef and implementing the feature method in Behaviour Pool.
https://help.sap.com/docs/ABAP_PLATFORM_NEW/fc4c71aa50014fd1b43721701471913d/dfc68f6275454c41b53510dacaec51d6.html?locale=en-US&version=202110.000